# Prove that every nonzero element of R is either a unit or a zero–divisor.

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification, ring-theory, ideals

Let $R$ be a finite commutative ring with unity. Prove that every nonzero element of $R$ is either a unit or a zero–divisor.

Sol:

Let $a\not=0 $

Because $R $is finite then

$a^j=a$ , then $(a^j -a )=0$

$a (a^{j-1}-1) =0$

If $a\not=0$ then $a$ is zero divisor
and $a^j a^{-1} = a^{j-2}a=1 $ so $a$ is unit

is true to prove this theorm by this way ? ,if not what is true ?
Thanks  for all

Comment: But , my prove is it true ?because l am little bit confused ?

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate. The OP here asks specifically if his/her own proof works or not.

Comment: @user1551 and a logical consequence of that line of thinking is that you create a loophole through which arbitrarily many duplicates can be made. If this person had a solution to a problem posted on this site, then the advisable thing to do is to *post it as a solution*.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2710194/29335